# Raw vs cheap honey for a turbo cyser

Tags: cider, honey

I'm planning on brewing a cyser using 4L of preservative free apple juice, Lalvin EC-1118 yeast and ~500g of honey.

Would you advise using a raw and unfiltered honey or just a regular off the supermarket shelf honey?

Is there much of a difference in the end product? Is it worth spending more for it?

Lastly, would you recommend adding some tea? I always do this for my other turbo ciders for tannins but have never made or tasted a cyser before so I'm unfamiliar with the taste profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheap honey is usually cheap for a reason. Check the label - it may contain artificial ingredients (e.g. various sugar syrup blends, flavorings, colorants). Be especially careful with anything labeled "product of China". While China does produce good quality honey, many supermarket products are blends, which means [they can be dodgy](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2021/nov/28/bee-aware-do-you-know-what-is-in-that-cheap-jar-of-honey).

If you want a good end product, you must start with good ingredients. Artificial honey may behave unpredictably in a fermentation.

That said, trying it is the best way to find out what will happen. A pair of side-by-site mini fermentations (I use 2 liter soda bottles for such experiments) should give you a decent comparison between the effect that different ingredients have on your end product.

Comment: Great response, thank you very much!